# Reading a datafile (abalone) and converting to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

When I try to load the UCI abalone data file as follows:

```
dattyp = [('sex',object),('length',float),('diameter',float),('height',float),('whole weight',float),('shucked weight',float),('viscera weight',float),('shell weight',float),('rings',int)]

abalone_data = np.loadtxt('C:/path/abalone.dat',dtype = dattyp, delimiter = ',')

print(abalone_data.shape)
print(abalone_data[0])
>>(4177,)
  ('M',  0.455,  0.365,  0.095,  0.514,  0.2245,  0.101,  0.15, 15)
```

`Abalone_data` is an array with 1 column instead of 9. Later on, when I want to add other data as extra columns, this gives me problems. Is there any way to transform this data to a `(4177, 9)` matrix where I can do the usual adding of columns etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [unpack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) parameter to `numpy.loadtxt()`. Then you can [numpy.transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) the newly created numpy array to get the required shape of array.

```
import numpy as np

dattyp = [('sex',object),('length',float),('diameter',float),('height',float),('whole weight',float),('shucked weight',float),('viscera weight',float),('shell weight',float),('rings',int)]

abalone_data = np.loadtxt('C:/path/abalone.dat',dtype = dattyp, delimiter = ',', unpack=True)
abalone_data = np.array((abalone_data)).transpose()

print(abalone_data.shape)
```

**Out:**

```
(4177, 9)
```

**From the documentation:**

> unpack : bool, optional
>
> If True, the returned array is transposed, so that arguments may be
>   unpacked using x, y, z = loadtxt(...). When used with a structured
>   data-type, arrays are returned for each field. Default is False.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

abalone_data = pd.read_csv('C:/path/abalone.dat', header=None).values
abalone_data.shape
```

OUtput:

```
(4177, 9)
```